# multiple ^| pipe within for loop (batch file)

Tags: batch-file

Is it possible to have mutiple pipe commands within a loop?

```
:: ------file(filter.txt) with contents which should be filtered---------
.mp3
.mp4
.wav
.jpg
.png
:: --------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to filter all files which contains the strings in filter.txt like:

`dir /a:-d /b | find /v ".mp3" | find /v ".mp4" | find /v ".wav" | find /v ".jpg" | find /v ".png"`

The point is that my entry has a lot more than shown in this example
I want to have this in a for loop but this is not working for me

`for /f "tokens=* delims=;" %%a in (filter.txt) do (| find /v "%a)`

Comment: You’re not using find correctly, see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15308/how-to-use-find-command-to-search-for-multiple-extensions or google Linux find multiple extensions

Comment: is there a way to do it with a batch file?

Comment: You need one properly constructed ‘find’ statement. Period.   There is no need for multiple pipes.   What you’ve constructed above doesn’t work at all.  But what you are trying to do you can find examples of very easily—I found one for you, many others available by googling “Linux find multiple extensions”